# How to get an IEnumerable<T1> of members of the class T2 in a Enumerable<T2> using Linq? (C#)

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Suppose I have:

```
 public class foobar
 {
    public int lorem;
    public int ipsum;
 }

 IEnumerable<foobar> items = new List<foobar>();
 items.add(new foobar(){lorem = 0, ipsum = 0};
 items.add(new foobar(){lorem = 1, ipsum = 1};
```

How can I get a IEnumerable of all "lorem" in "items" using Linq?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following

```
var allLorems = items.Select(x => x.lorem);
```

Comment: In what way is that "without using LINQ"? I'm more asking because it's been accepted than anything else...

Comment: @Jon: OP asked "using LINQ" not "without using LINQ"

Comment: Jon...looks like the original question was editted so that it now says 'using Linq' rather than 'without using Linq'.

Confused me too.

Comment: ouch! I use that, how could I not see a so obvious solution?

Comment: Justin: I'm glad it's not just me. I'm *sure* I saw it say "without using LINQ"!

Comment: And strictly speaking, the LINQ syntax would be (from x in items select x.lorem) but everybody calls the LINQ-supporting lambdas LINQ anyway ;)

Comment: Jon: You're not the only one...almost posted the old foreach loop solution since he didn't want LINQ.

Comment: Adam: When you say "strictly speaking" can you provide details of this "strict" meaning of LINQ? LINQ is a fuzzy term, and always has been. I don't believe it's sensible to *only* include query expressions.

Comment: @Jon: My statement was more tonque-in-cheek as this is a pretty semantic distinction, but given what LINQ (as an acronym) stands for then I think it's entirely sensible to have a "stict" qualification for LINQ be that it's a query expression. Obviously it's convenient to refer to the usage of the lambdas that a LINQ query utilizes in its execution as LINQ, but I don't think it's entirely accurate. Nothing WRONG with it (again, purely semantic distinction), but nonetheless not 100% accurate.

Answer (score 2):

I think you mean:

```
 List<foobar> items = new List<foobar>();
 items.Add(new foobar(){lorem = 0, ipsum = 0});
 items.Add(new foobar(){lorem = 1, ipsum = 1});
```

and then:

```
var lorems=from i in items select i.lorem;
```

Comment: For a simple "single projection" or "single filter" I think it's clearer just to call the extension method, as per Jared's answer.